# Trying to do a Proof of Concept of poisoning 'ls' binary to hide files and folders

Tags: linux, filesystems, ls, c

I am currently trying to modify 'ls.c' source file in order to hide files and folders containing the word *hidden*. After doing some research, I've found that this could be possible by adding this code into 'ls.c' source file:

```
            char attr_command[1024] = "attr -Lqg hidden "; // Oh, dear. That's bad
            int attr_code;
            strcat(attr_command, d->d_name);
            strcat(attr_command, " >/dev/null 2>&1");
            attr_code = system(attr_command);
            if (!attr_code)
                    continue;
```

This code would have to be added after the following line:

```
while ((d = readdir(dp))) {
```

We can get the coreutils source files (including ls.c) via 'git clone git://git.suckless.org/sbase'

So after running 'make' with the modified 'ls.c' source file, the file 'hidden' is still showing up.

I need to modify 'ls.c' to really hide files and folders.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I am actually using the freshly built 'ls' I've built with 'make' by doing ./ls. And no I do not use the original 'ls' binary that was originally built with my Ubuntu for testing if file 'hidden' is really hidden or not.

Comment: err, do you mean to hide files with the string "hidden" in their _names_? Or something else?

Comment: yes this is exactly what I'm trying to do; hide files with the string 'hidden'. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[The `attr` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/attr.1.html) deals with [*extended attributes*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/xattr.7.html), particularly in relation to the XFS filesystem. (It also works with ext4, but I suppose `getfattr` and `setfattr` are meant for general, filesystem-independent use.)

That is to say, `attr -Lqg hidden "$filename"` doesn't check anything about the file's *name*, but it checks if an extended attribute called `hidden` is set on the file.

If you want to check if the file name contains a particular string, you should probably use [the `strstr()` function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strstr.3.html).

Since `d->d_name` contains the name of the file being processed, something like this might work.

```
if (strstr(d->d_name, "hidden") == 0) { ...
```

That doesn't mean you couldn't base file hiding on extended attributes... But even if you do, it might be better to look up the actual system calls used for that. `system()` forks off a shell and the external process, and with a long directory listing, that may be noticeably slow.

Also, note that modifying `ls` will do nothing to other programs that can also give a file listing. They may be as simple as `find`, or `printf "%s\n" *`.

Comment: I've tried adding system("grep -v hidden"); but it doesn't work unfortunately. Do you have an idea of the correct code to add with system() ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Allright so I've kinda found a workaround to "hide" a string for 'ls' by adding the following line in 'ls.c' after line 261 (thanks to ilkkachu for his answer below):

```
                if (strstr(d->d_name, "HIDDEN") == 0)
                    return 0;
```

Probably not the best solution but hey it works :)

If anyone out there would like to suggest a better option/solution, please do it, I would love to have more options and a better one if possible !

Thanks